# Unable to process binding "click" - Knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I'm getting this error when i load the page with my code:

```
 <div class="container" >

        <div class="row" id="content">   
            <p data-bind="click: clickme">CLICK</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
    var viewModel = function() {
        var self = this;

        self.clickme = function(){
            console.log("Hello!");
        }
    }        
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("content"));      
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `ko.applyBindings(new viewModel(), document.getElementById("content"));`

Comment: @JeffMercado Hi, thanks for your feedback, i tried this but im still getting the same error...

Comment: Nonsense, given the code you provided and that markup, it should work. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e0exat32/) If _this_ doesn't work for your code, then that means your code doesn't match what you posted here.

Comment: @JeffMercado this is all : http://i.imgur.com/tIwwmGo.jpg, can some of the linked links in the head tag cause this problem???

Comment: i found my problem, the jquery.slim.min.js script in the head was the problem, i changed that and now the code is working as it was.